# laravel-dompdf doesn't download pdf

Tags: laravel

In my print function:

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return @$pdf->stream();
```

From what I read, this should automatically download a pdf, but instead, I get a long string (which is at least in a pdf format). I'm using Homestead, so I'm not sure if that's the issue.

In my console:

```
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text ]
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Producer (dompdf <5c98652> + CPDF)
/CreationDate (D:20170106022200+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20170106022200+00'00')
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000]
/Parent 3 0 R
/Contents 7 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 66 >>
stream
xã2Ð300P@&Ò¹BMôÍÌ
-õ,MBRôÝ¢
!i

Ñ!©Å%±
!^
®!îC
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/BaseFont /Times-Bold
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000074 00000 n 
0000000120 00000 n 
0000000274 00000 n 
0000000303 00000 n 
0000000435 00000 n 
0000000538 00000 n 
0000000675 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 9
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 5 0 R
>>
startxref
783
%%EOF
```

Comment: it's in pdf format but it shows the string instead download? i think it's caused by the **http header**.

Comment: use `return response($pdf->stream())->header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'));`

Comment: @Bagus Tesa I got the same response, but with 
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control:       no-cache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="document.pdf"
Content-Type:        application/pdf
in front. For additional info: I'm using Vue to call the controller, so I'm not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: weird, tried it with `curl`? or just another browser?

Comment: @BagusTesa No luck on Mozilla either. How do I use curl to send a get request?

Comment: if you have `GitBash` you will get `wget` and `curl` too, [here's tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl/). also, i think it had something to do with `Vue`, but i'm not sure, never tried `Vue` before - [here some discussion in laracast about downloading file using vue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/download-file-1?page=1). ps, using `curl` you can add `-v` after the `curl` part for verbose mode (header both request and response will be printed to screen)

Comment: @BagusTesa You're right, it's a Vue issue! Browsing directly to the route worked. I'll try the solution in the link you gave. You want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use wkhtmltopdf.

click on below link, it may help you .
http://packalyst.com/packages/package/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf

PDF::setOutputMode('F'); // force to file
$data = PDF::html('folder.htmlfile',['key' => $value],$pdfname);